# First rect returning the infinite frame

Tags: ios, uitextview

i am trying to get the position rect of the last character in textview which is added in a cell.
what happens when i reload the cell then this method returns infinite rect. I don't know why this is happening. Please help me to correct it. My code so far is below-

```
UITextPosition *Pos2 = [_txt_EventName positionFromPosition: _txt_EventName.endOfDocument offset: 0];
    UITextPosition *Pos1 = [_txt_EventName positionFromPosition: _txt_EventName.endOfDocument offset: -1];

    UITextRange *range = [_txt_EventName textRangeFromPosition:Pos1 toPosition:Pos2];

    CGRect rect=[_txt_EventName firstRectForRange:range];

    CGPoint lastCharPoint=rect.origin;
```

Comment: An infinite rectangle is often returned as a kind of "error" marker. So make sure the range is actually valid.

Comment: i checked the ranged and is valid always.

Comment: I added if ([_txt_EventName textInRange:range]==nil) {
            NSLog(@"Invalid TextRange");
        }
after calculating the range but this code doesn't execute for a single time.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into the same problem (actually found your question accidentally) and solved my problem by calling `layoutIfNeeded` on my text view. 
After this call the rectangle that gets returned is correctly calculated. Spent a lot of time figuring this out.

Good luck,
Z.

Comment: That helped! Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, but `layoutIfNeeded` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin I used to override the LayoutSubViews method and call my function after base.LayoutSubViews().