# Dynamically move a uiview at the end of a text string

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a very simple screen.

a `UITextView` and `UITextField`.

basically, what I want to achieve is that when a user types something into the `UITextField`, it goes into the `UITextView`.

Obviously the `UITextView` has `userInteractionEnabled : NO` and it won't never show the keyboard. 
To make it nicer I also wanted the cursor to be always shown (kinda matrix talking to you :-). 
To achieve this i placed a little subview into the `UITextView` with a width of 2 and a height of 20 (enough for my font size) and the following piece of code into the `viewDidLoad`:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.cursorView.alpha = 0 }, completion: {(animated: Bool) -> Void in
            self.cursorView.alpha = 1
    })
```

Now, the question is: how can I dynamically move the `cursorView` according to the text that will be written (automaGically) into the `UITextView`?

Is there a way to recognise its length - position or anything else?

Comment: why not just use a ▌symbol at the end?

Comment: 'cause it's not blinking :-)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11487125/4539192) answer may help you. You can find out the space or x,y occupied by a word at a particular position in a `UITextView` and use it to animatedly move your cursor!