# Get X/Y position of substring in multi-line + scrollable TextView in SwiftUI and macOS 11

Tags: swiftui, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextview

### Plan

I have implemented a TextView into my Swift-app (macOS 11) using the following implementation, which makes the TextView scrollable by placing it into a ScrollViewer:

https://gist.github.com/unnamedd/6e8c3fbc806b8deb60fa65d6b9affab0

Now, I'm trying to display annotations on the side of the text, which should eventually look something like this:

[image: Annotations]

I planned to achieve this by

1. **Setting a custom AttributedString-key** to the NSAttributedString of the TextView
2. **Add a second ScrollView on the left side**, which contains the annotations, **and synchronise the scroll position** of both ScrollViews (i.e., the left one and the one in the TextView.)
3. **Calculate the Y-position of each annotation** using the relevant substring **and place/draw the annotation/connecting line**

### Problem

I tried to evaluate the Y-Position of a substring using the **textView.firstRect** function (which I found in all the other, old SO-questions), however, it does not seem to return the correct values unless the position of a substring within the first line of the TextView is used.

```
    class TextViewExtended: NSTextView {    

func getAllRectangles() {
    for CurRange in self.selectedRanges {
        self.layoutManager!.ensureLayout(for: self.textContainer!) // S. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30752520/2624880
        let CurRangeAsNSRange:NSRange = CurRange as! NSRange
        var actualRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.attributedString().length)
        let rect = self.firstRect(forCharacterRange: CurRangeAsNSRange, actualRange: &actualRange)
    }}}
```

### Question

**What would be to correct way to determine the coordinates of a substring of a TextView in SwiftUI & macOS 11? Or does anybody have an even simpler idea how I could achieve this?**

Thanks a lot in advance for any advise!

Ps. I have omitted the full code of the TextView implementation since it follows the above tutorial closely; please let me know if I should add additional code.

Comment: SwiftUI natively does not give such flexibility for now. You should continue work with NSTextView for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Asperi. Stupid question but does that mean I shouldn't implement a TextView in a SwiftUI project as shown in the link (i.e. with a NSViewRepresentable, Coordinator, NSTextView within a NSScrollView, etc.) but rather make an AppKit project?

Comment: Who said that AppKit variant is worse or impossible? Who said that it is impossible to combine them? Take into account that SwiftUI is 1 year-old, AppKit lives tens years (since NeXT)...

Comment: Thanks again, @Asperi Didn't mean this offensive in any way! I'm still very new to Swift(UI) and that's why I'm quite confused when I should use which framework (and e.g. how I could use the native NSTextView here). I think, I'll wait for feature Swift updates in that case! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the rect using the `actualRange`. some thing like this:

```swift
rect = textView.firstRect(forCharacterRange: range, actualRange: &actualRange)
while actualRange.upperBound < rangeToCheck.upperBound {
    rangeToCheck.length = (rangeToCheck.upperBound - actualRange.upperBound)
    rangeToCheck.location = actualRange.upperBound
    rect = textView.firstRect(forCharacterRange: rangeToCheck, actualRange: &actualRange)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, `var rect = self.firstRect(forCharacterRange: CurRangeAsNSRange, actualRange: &actualRange)` seems to work now, so this issue is resolved (to be honest, I didn't manage to implement your while loop, but it seems to work anyway)! Cheers

Comment: Finally figured out how to get the position _within the TextView itself (not the window)_ : `layoutManager!.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: rangeToCheck, in: self.textContainer!)`. Correct this rect by the height/width of  `textContainerInset` of the TextView and the current scroll position (using `enclosingScrollView.documentVisibleRect.origin`) and you've got the correct position!